# Listening for an event from Reddit Enhancement Suite

Tags: javascript, jquery, reddit

I searched around and couldn't find anyone with the same question, so hopefully it's not redundant.

I'm trying to make a chrome extension modify the DOM every time Reddit Enhancement Suite loads a new page (with never ending auto scroll or whatever).

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

So from one chrome extension, I need to listen to events on the other one. Actually subscribing to the events is pretty straight forward, but I'm not sure how to go about finding the events/element to subscribe to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RES author here.

There's an event that Never Ending Reddit fires just for you!

https://github.com/honestbleeps/Reddit-Enhancement-Suite/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=neverendingload

Comment: This is beautiful - Thanks! Next time I will search the RES source code a bit before asking!

Comment: no worries, not exactly the most intuitive thing to search for. Looking forward to seeing whatever it is you're working on!

Comment: [Here's the repo](https://github.com/amoskyler/redditpreviewer)
I've never written a chrome extension before, and it's pretty basic. It needs a reorganization/and some stuff cut out, but I'd love any feedback you have.